# How to terminate a python multiprocess pool early

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pool

I've recently started poking around at the multiprocessing module and find the pool.map function very useful for parsing a large array very quickly. Is there a way to terminate a pool early however? Lets say I have a huge list and I want to find a number in a list, check if it's devisable by x, and then return true if it is and terminate the rest of the pool early, how might I go about doing this? For a proof of concept, I'm trying to find prime numbers from 3 to infinity (the least efficient way possible). Here's an example:

```
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial

finders=multiprocessing.pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1)

def is_devis(x, number):
    if number%x==0:
        return True

if __name__=="__main__":
    Primes=[3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, ...]
    x=3
    while True:
        x=x+2
        func=partial(is_devis, x)
        results=finders.map(func, Primes)
        if not (True in results):
            Primes.append(x)
```

I might not completely grasp how multiprocess pools or the pool.map function works but from what I understand, it will split an *iterable* up evenly for you and then spread them out amongst the pool and the workers will continue until all the processes return or finish. Is there a way to terminate a pool as soon as one process returns a value? I have looked at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) on multiprocess.pool but it is noted

> Worker processes within a Pool typically live for the complete duration of the Pool’s work queue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When building application using multiprocessing, the actual application is relevant. If I take the example with the primes, I would do it like that: Give a max number which will be the last one to be tested. Create a function which take a number and tells you if its a prime. Map this function on a range up to the max number. Thus the end criterion is not "a process returns a value" but the maximum number preset. If you want advice on how to build your multiprocessing application, please give an explanation about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Mathieu Thanks for the input. I don't currently have a specific project in mind other than that example. I'm actually working on that as a project, just a way to find as many prime numbers as possible and observe how the computer handles it. I would also implement a way to save them all to a file. But the question still remains the same unfortunately. Would it be possible to terminate a pool based on the result of a process mid way through the pool?

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37691552/how-to-get-all-pool-apply-async-processes-to-stop-once-any-one-process-has-found/37700081#37700081

Comment: @noxdafox Yes, that's actually exactly what I was looking for. With a little tweaking it has fit the job perfectly. Not sure why I wasn't able to find that answer in my searches before but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A naive approach would be to have a global flag that a thread can set when it finds an answer. In each of the other threads, you can periodically check the flag and have the thread terminate if it is set.

Comment: Note that this requires that the separate processes *share* the flag, which means putting it into a Manager object or using the shared-memory primitives.

Comment: I was thinking of something of that sort. Unfortunately, when a new process is made, from my understanding, when a new process is created, it is creating an entirely new python instance witch doesn't share any global variables. As @torek was mentioning, you can get around this with a specific type of shared memory variable. I have tried using this approach but because pool().map only accepts a iterable object, using the partial function throws an error. "RuntimeError: Synchronized objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance"

Comment: @BobserLuck: Linux `multiprocess` uses `fork()` so that children inherit (copies of) parent settings, including Manager objects. Manager objects detect the fork and connect on a communications channel to share updates. The shared memory primitives are simpler internally and thus more efficient, but harder to use. I think Managers can be used on Windows but I'm not sure of the details.