# Terminating multiprocess pool when one of the workers found proper solution

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I've created a program, which can be sum up to something like this:

```
from itertools import combinations
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, t2):
        self.another_class_object = t2

def function_1(self,n):
   a = 2
   while(a <= n):
       all_combs = combinations(range(n),a)
       for comb in all_combs:
           if(another_class_object.function_2(comb)):
              return 1
       a += 1
   return -1
```

Function `combinations` is imported from `itertools`. `Function_2` returns `True` or `False` depending on the input and is a method in another class object, e.g.:

```
class Test_2(object):

def __init__(self, list):
    self.comb_list = list

def function_2(self,c):
    return c in self.comb_list
```

Everything is working just fine. But now I want to change it a little bit and implement multiprocessing. I found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447055/python-multiprocess-pool-how-to-exit-the-script-when-one-of-the-worker-process) that shows an example of how to exit the script when one of the worker process determines no more work needs to be done. So I made following changes:

1. added a definition of pool into `__init__` method: `self.pool = Pool(processes=8)`
2. created a callback function:

   ```
   all_results = []
   def callback_function(self, result):
       self.all_results.append(result)
       if(result):
           self.pool.terminate()
   ```
3. changed `function_1`:

   ```
   def function_1(self,n):
       a = 2
       while(a <= n):
          all_combs = combinations(range(n),a)
          for comb in all_combs:
              self.pool.apply_async(self.another_class_object.function_2, args=comb, callback=self.callback_function)
          #self.pool.close()
          #self.pool.join()
          if(True in all_results):
              return 1
          a += 1
      return -1
   ```

Unfortunately, it does not work as I expected. Why? After debugging it looks like the callback function is never reached. I thought that it would be reached by every worker. Am I wrong? What can be the problem?

Comment: For starters don't pass instance methods to your `multiprocessing.Pool` facilities (or multiprocessing code in general) as that's one bag of hurt you don't want to open.

Answer (score 1):

I did not try your code as such, but I tried your structure. Are you sure the problem is in callback function and not the worker function? I did not manage to get apply_async launch a single instance of the worker function if the function was a class method. It just did not do anything. Apply_async completes without error but it does not implement the worker.

As soon as I moved the worker function (in your case another_class_object.function2) as a standalone global function outside classes, it started working as expected and the callback was triggered normally. The callback function, in contrast, seems to work fine as a class method.

There seems to be discussion about this for example here: [Why can I pass an instance method to multiprocessing.Process, but not a multiprocessing.Pool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318290/why-can-i-pass-an-instance-method-to-multiprocessing-process-but-not-a-multipro)

Is this in any way useful?

Hannu

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: ... not work as I expected. ... What can be the problem?

It's always necessary to `get()` the Results from `pool.apply_async(...` to see the Errors from the Pool Processes.

Change to the following:

```
pp = []
for comb in all_combs:
    pp.append(pool.apply_async(func=self.another_class_object.function_2, args=comb, callback=self.callback_function))

pool.close()

for ar in pp:
    print('ar=%s' % ar.get())
```

> **And you will see this Error:**
>
> ```
> TypeError: function_2() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
> ```

Fix for this Error, change `args=comb` to `args=(comb,)`:

```
pp.append(pool.apply_async(func=self.another_class_object.function_2, args=(comb,), callback=self.callback_function))
```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***