# How to terminate a multiprocess in python when a given condition is met?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Let's say I have the function:

```
def f():  
    while True:          
        x = generate_something()  
        if x == condition:  
            return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p=Pool(4)
```

I want to run this function in a multiprocess and when one of the processes meets my function's condition, I want all other processes to stop.

Comment: Check out the signals module. You can signal a process to stop

Comment: You can share some of the process results to multiprocessing.Queue and monitor it with other processes, so if condition's met - do smth. I use capped collection in MongoDB as message stream to switch on/off processes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `event` and `terminate` in `multiprocessing` since you want to stop all processes once condition is met in one of the child process.

Check the below working example in which I am creating two processes which will check the value of variable `x` is 5 or not.

Once, one of the process sets the value of `x` to `5`, event is set.

`Event` is `set` or `unset` is continuously checked in `main` code.

**Code:**

```
import random
import multiprocessing
import sys
import time

def generate_something():
    return random.choice(range(10))

def f(event):
    while True:
        x = generate_something()
        print "Value is ",x
        if x == 5:
            print "Got what I am searching for."
            event.set()
        time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    jobs = []
    #Create Event
    event = multiprocessing.Event()

    #Create two processes
    for i in range(2):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f,args=(event,))
        p.start()
        jobs.append(p)

    #Check whether event is set or not
    #When set close all child processes
    while True:
        if event.is_set():
            print "Exiting all child processess.."
            for i in jobs:
                #Terminate each process
                i.terminate()
            #Terminating main process
            sys.exit(1)
        time.sleep(2)
```

**Output:**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\python.exe" C:/Users/punddin/PycharmProjects/demo/a.py
Value is  4
Value is  2
Value is  7
Value is  6
Value is  3
Value is  4
Value is  8
Value is  3
Value is  8
Value is  1
Value is  9
Value is  9
Value is  1
Value is  6
Value is  5
Got what I am searching for.
Value is  6
Exiting all processess..
```

Comment: Nicely summed up by Dinesh chcha!

Comment: I'm am interested to know how this compares to [using a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33450972). Is one better practice? Is one more efficient?